# SMTP Keep open for built-in PHP mail()

Tags: php, smtp

I'm using PHP's built-in `mail()` function to send bulk email, and want to keep SMTP connection open. Is there any option like PHPMailer's  `$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;`

I don't want to use PHPMailer.